# Confused with the ending of The Man In High Castle

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-in-the-high-castle

I finished watching 4th season of The Man in High Castle but can't understand the ending. In the end following happens:

> A portal to a parallel universe opens up and people start coming out of it.

Who are all those people?

Comment: I have the same question. My assumption is the ending is a statement of ideology or evolution of mankind. But it’s just an assumption.

Comment: I assume they're all the people who had been exterminated by the Nazis. Where exactly they're coming from, and why, I have no idea.

Comment: That's exactly the question I was looking for. Those people are actually walking in paying no attention to what is happening around, not even noticing all members of the Resistance standing at there.

Answer (score 2):

[In the November 19, 2019, issue of ew.com](https://ew.com/tv/2019/11/19/the-man-in-the-high-castle-ending-explained-series-finale/), they interview the 4th season showrunner, [David Scarpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Scarpa), and he said:

> As she returns to the mines, which the Resistance occupied in the chaos, the portal opens and one of Juliana’s visions comes to pass. Men, women, and children from “everywhere” begin to walk through to her reality. Their faces aren’t clearly visible against the glaring light from the portal, and Scarpa confirms to EW their identities aren’t necessarily crucial for the desired effect of this scene. Are they coming from all parts of the multiverse? Are they alt-world versions of those who died in Juliana’s world?

> “There was a considerable amount of discussion between myself and my partner [director and executive producer] Daniel Percival, as well as others, in terms of how much we wanted to be explanatory in that final scene,” Scarpa says. “Part of the intention was to invite the audience to have their own interpretation of what they’re seeing on screen.”

> However, he does reveal something. “What should be clear to any viewer is that the portal is, essentially, open and it is going to remain open. In effect, what that means is two worlds have become one. There’s a doorway from one world into the next, and now people can move freely between them. What does that mean? You have ordinary people, in some interpretations, who have been called to this event, who are moving through the portal, and these two worlds are going to be fused.”

Comment: Your answer would make me think that all restrictions have been removed from the door. Now, anyone can go through it. Including people who are alive in both worlds. Maybe, the people drawn to the event are those that have a particular longing or feeling of connectedness with a loved one who is dead in their own world and Alice in the other world. However, wouldn’t that mean that two of the same person could eventually meet?

Comment: @DeanF. since the series ended and they left it purposely open to interpretation, the meaning is up to you.